# What's causing this subscript out of range error?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array that's being filled into a template, destination cell is A3 (first two rows are headers). The array fills the first employee row, but then I get a `subscript out of range error` after the first row of the array is filled on this line:

```
 Dest.Offset(destcol, destrow) = Data(sourcerow, sourcecol)
```

rest of script for reference:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Data, Last, Login
    Dim sourcerow As Long, sourcecol As Long, destrow As Long, destcol As Long
    Dim Dest As Range


    'Refer to the template
    Set Wb = Workbooks("Default_Changes_Template.xlsx")

    'Refer to the destination cell
    Set Dest = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")

    'Read in all data
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Full Population")
        Data = .Range("AL3", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Wb.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Process the data
    For sourcerow = 1 To UBound(Data)
        'Manager changes?
        If Data(sourcerow, 1) <> Last Then
            'Skip the first
            If sourcerow > 1 Then
                'Scroll into the view
                Dest.Select
                'Save a copy
                Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
                              ValidFileName(Login & " - " & Last & " - " & "Default Adjustments.xlsx")
            End If

            'Clear the employees
            Dest.Resize(3, Columns.Count - Dest.Column).ClearContents
            'Remember this manager
            Login = Data(sourcerow, 2)
            Last = Data(sourcerow, 1)

            'Start the next round
            destcol = 0
        End If

        'Write the employee data into the template
        destrow = 0

        For sourcecol = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            Dest.Offset(destcol, destrow) = Data(sourcerow, sourcecol)
            destrow = destrow + 1
        Next

        'Next column
        destcol = destcol + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't seem related to the subscript out of range, but note that `Range.Offset`'s parameters are *RowOffset* first and *ColumnOffset* second; looks like you have them backwards.

Comment: and make it this instead? `dest.offset(destcol, destrow) = Data(sourcerow,sourcecol)`?

Comment: `Dest.Offset(destrow, destcol)`  - row 1st, column 2nd right?

Comment: @BigBen, oh I want it to be row 3, column 1. and then after that have the destrow = destrow +1 to fill in the next employee

Comment: Apparently you wanted `For sourcecol = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)`.

Comment: @GSerg, does this state the upper bound of dimension 2 (columns) or since theyre switched in order is it stating upper bound of the rows?

Comment: `UBound(Data, 2)` is the upper bound of dimension 2. You know you need both because you are already using `UBound(Data)` (which is `UBound(Data, 1)`) for `sourcerow`, so it has to be another dimension for `sourcecol`.

Comment: @GSerg, you rock! Thank you so much